# validating alphanumeric input in textbox [VB2010]

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

im newbie here, im using **vb2010**,  i just need some help guys.

here's my problem.

i want to validate user's input on my textbox, when user input like this "**1a1:b2b:3c3**", my project should accept it. but when user input like this "**1a1b2b3c3**", it will show a msgbox that the format must be "**XXX:XXX:XXX**".thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done up a very quick example for you, more than enough to get you on the right track. I could have done it a different way, but I am sure this will get you going. I used MaxLength to determine that the user input at least 9 characters and if not let them know. I also made a function that passes the textbox's text into this and will go ahead and format it for you; saves the user time... besides we just need to make sure user primarily enters at least 9 characters anyways if I am correct... Good Luck!

```
Public Class Form1

Private strValidatedText As String = String.Empty
Private blnValid As Boolean = False

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Make sure user can only enter up to 9 values...
    With txtInput
        .MaxLength = 9
        .TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub btnValidate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnValidate.Click
    Dim strTextBox As String = txtInput.Text
    strValidatedText = ValidateText(strTextBox)
    Select Case blnValid
        Case True
            MessageBox.Show("It's valid! " & strValidatedText)
            txtInput.Clear()
            txtInput.Focus()
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show(strValidatedText)
            txtInput.Clear()
            txtInput.Focus()
    End Select
End Sub

Private Function ValidateText(ByVal strText As String)
    Dim strNewText As String = String.Empty
    If strText.Length = 9 Then
        strNewText = (strText.Substring(0, 3) & ":" & strText.Substring(3, 3) & ":" & strText.Substring(6, 3))
        blnValid = True
    Else
        strNewText = "There must be at least 9 characters in the textbox!"
        blnValid = False
    End If
    Return strNewText
End Function
End Class
```

Also at that point in the "Select Case blnValid", you can do what ever you would like with that string because it's global...

MrCodeXeR

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `MaskedTextBox` class, it will help you to take a formatted input from user. Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) example.

Answer (score -1):

I tried it with following code and it works fine in `VB 2010`. Just use this code before your variable declaration:

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" Then    'check if the textbox has a value
    MsgBox("Please Enter ID Number")
Return    'will return to the app
ElseIf Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then    'check if the entered value is a number
    MsgBox("ID Must Be A Number")
Return
```